# Intercepting Windows Messages from Webview2 (Edge/Chromium)

Tags: c++, winapi, webview, wndproc, webview2

I have recently migrated a project of mine to [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) and the last part I can't figure out is how to intercept the Windows Messages for the webview. My code is very similar to [webview/webview](https://github.com/webview/webview/blob/master/webview.h#L852) but I was unable to find help on their GitHub.

Previously, I was able to find the `hWnd` for the webview and use  [`SetWindowSubclass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) to add my own `wndproc` to the webview. However, I've used [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019) and tried `SetWindowSubclass` on all the windows that showed up there (see below) but none of them had any windows messages in my `wndproc` other than some window management ones I did not think were useful - The best I got was `WM_PARENTYNOTIFY`, but I am interested in `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_NCHITTEST` - neither of which I could find.

*My goal is to create a borderless, draggable, resizeable WebView2 based app.*

[image: Spy++ Output]

Comment: Why, though? WebView2 allows you to register delegates for events you are interested in. What *problem* are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: @IInspectable There is no way to register an event for `WM_NCHITTEST` for example. I am trying to achieve a borderless Webview2 that is draggable & resizeable. I had it working this way with previous Webview but now I am trying to migrate to Webview2

Comment: You should probably inject some javascript into the page, you're viewing, then you can write eventhandlers in javascript and use `window.chrome.webview2.postmessage` to report back to your C++ code.

Comment: @PoulBak I can do that for dragging the window but if I try to do that for resizing and I send WM_NCHITTEST, the cursor will flicker between what the webview is trying to send and what I am trying to send

Comment: In my previous webview1 framework, I fixed that by capturing and not propagating certain messages.

Comment: Can't you check those messages on form instead?

Comment: No, that is the problem. I have attached to everything I can find in spy++ but nothing reports those messages back

Comment: @Chris have you solved the problem of dragging a window with a webview2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the real window that controls and gets all this input is in another process. You just see a window that shows the output in your process.

Look into Spy++. Everything below `Chrome_WidgetWin_0` belongs to a new process (`MSEDGEWEBVIEW2`) and is not part of your process. So you can't subclass such a window with the normal techniques.

So if you want to subclass this window. You need to inject a new DLL into this new process. This DLL might subclass the real window. And this DLL might communicate with you hosting program via any IPC.